# determining state space based on area

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, state-space

I have been tasked with figuring out a state space for a problem based on the area of a rectangle.  It seems that I have made my state space far too large and need some feedback.
 So far I have an area that has a value fo 600 for a y axis and 300 for an x axis.  I determined the number of points to be

> (600 x 300) !  or 180,000!

Therefore my robot would need to inspect this many potential spaces, before I apply an algorithm.

This number seems quite high and if that is the case it would make my problem unsolveable before I die especially if I implement the algorithm incorrectly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated especially if my math is off in determining the number of points.

***EDIT***
I was under the impression to see how many pairs of points you would have to take the cartesian product of the total available points.  Which in turn would be (600x300)! .  If this is incorrect please let me know.

Comment: @Henk Holterman As the ultimate answer is 42, I guess a (6x7)! is a better answer :)

Comment: i cant use 6x3 as there are 600 x 300 possible points.  I suppose the better question is what could I apply to show that it scaled properly?

Comment: @Woot4Moo: If there are 600 X 300 possible points the number of points is unmistakably 180000. Unless you give us some more info about the problem, there's really not much we can do.

Comment: Yes that is the number of points I need the number of pairs, which in turn would determine the number of states.  Because you must occupy a point (x,y) I would need to have all available pairs

Comment: @Henk its quite easy to pick up on sarcasm in the written word =p .  Perhaps some feedback as to what extra information is needed would be nice

Comment: @Henk a bit hard to produce a piece of code when you don't have the proper assumptions down for an algorithm wouldn't you agree?

Comment: What I want to do to those points is moot, my question is purely about the number of potential states based on a a X b board.

Comment: Why is 180000 infeasible? Robots are immortal, so it doesn't matter that you'll be dead long before it figures out the answer. The robot will eventually figure it out, and science will stagger forward!

Comment: if its 180,000 factorial we will all be dead =[

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I don't understand where you get the factorial from. From what I understand, your state is a pair rather than a permutation of cells. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @MAK I think it was a miscommunication on my part, I did mean pair.  Thanks for your clarifications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the number of "points" (as defined in mathematics - the only relevant definition) in a rectangle of any size (non-zero area) is infinity. Why? Because a point does not necessarily have to have integer coordinates - there can be a point at (0,0), (0,0.1), (0.001), (0,0.0001) and so on. I think what you mean by points in your question is that all points must have integer coordinates (i.e. [lattice points](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatticePoint.html)), or alternately, "cells" in a rectangular grid (like cells on a chess board). Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

There are 600 rows and 300 coloumns. This means that there are 600 * 300 = 180,000 different cells. It follows that there are [nCr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)(180,000,2) =  16,199,910,000 unique pairs in the grid. I am assuming you consider the pair ((1,1),(2,2)) and ((2,2),(1,1)) equivalent. Otherwise, there are 180,000*180,000 = 32,400,000,000 pairs.

Comment: I guess (!) means (factorial) in the question.

Comment: @belisarius: I thought so too. Doesn't make sense as punctuation :).

Comment: @MAK sorry if it was trivial. I just don't understand what is a "state" for the OP.

Comment: @belisarius: From what I understand of the question, the state space is the set of pairs of cells in the grid. Each state is a pair of the form ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)).

Comment: @MAK: That is what I read too, but how is such a vector/move a 'State' ?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: It appears that the OP wants to run some sort of procedure on this state space (probably a search algorithm like BFS/DFS/Dijkstra etc.). I think the pair represents the state used in the algorithm. Probably something like the position of two objects on the screen, like the 'state' of a chess board is the positions of the pieces. But I think this answer can be best answered by the OP himself. I'm just saying what I thought.

Comment: @MAK you would be correct in your assumptions.  Also (!) was factorial, as I was under the impression that was the only way to really show it.    Thanks for the link to lattice points, I will take a look into this and most likely mark this as the answer.